# Add onclick attribute to image when insertEmbed quill editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, quill

I have inserted one image into Quill editor user this code

```
 const index = self._quillInstance.getSelection();
  self._quillInstance.insertEmbed(index.index, 'image', img.src);
  self._quillInstance.formatText(index.index, index.index + 1, 'height', '256px');
  self._quillInstance.formatText(index.index, index.index + 1, 'width', (256 * img.width / img.height) + 'px');
  self._quillInstance.formatText(index.index, index.index + 1, 'alt', (self._lstKeyImageBase64.length - 1).toString());
  self._quillInstance.formatText(index.index, index.index + 1, 'onclick', self.handleClickImg);
```

But the onclick attribute cannot insert to the img tag in editor container.
How can I insert onclick event to this img was inserted to Quill?

Comment: probably because it expects a string value for the html

Answer (score 1):

`formatText` is meant for formatting and is not built to support inserting arbitrary HTML attributes. Also Quill needs to know about the format (by default height, width, and alt are defined for images). To add additional formats take a look at [Content and Formatting](https://quilljs.com/guides/how-to-customize-quill/#content-and-formatting)